# Jquery preloader bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question I don't understand, is this kind of bug or not, I have a jquery script that makes preloader disappears, but when I refreshing page after some 2 or more times, it bugs out and doesn't disappears when it should. Then I refresh the page again preloader disappears how it should.
Why I think its a bug because I have also script that doesn`t let website scroll, and it works perfectly and it uses almost the same script.

My code in main.js (I linked to html):

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'JS/jquery-3.6.1.min.js';
newScript.onload = function () {
    alert("Script is ready!");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        aler("JQuery is ready!");
    });
};
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(newScript);

newScript.onload = function () {
    $(".loader-wrapper", 'body').fadeOut("slow");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a bit code because it started not loading everytime when I wanted to add more script. so I used this code, I hope that I helped someone :)

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".loader-wrapper", 'body').fadeOut("slow");
});
```